# What is the line to add to vimrc for storing .swp files in /tmp on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I feel like I've literally tried everything, but no matter what I add to vimrc, I can't get it to store its annoying .swp files in /tmp. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I've obviously looked up this issue extensively, but again, no command I enter seems to work. I always end up with:

```
E510: Can't make backup file
(add ! to override)
```

Things I've tried:

```
set backupdir=$~/tmp//
set directory=$~/tmp//
set backupdir=~/tmp//
set backupdir=$HOME~/tmp//
set backupdir=/tmp//
```

I mean you name it, I've tried it. So, explicitly, what is the ***exact*** code I need to type in vimrc to make it so vim saves it's .swp files in my temporary folder, instead of cluttering my workspace?

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you want to save the files, in `/tmp` (at system level) or in `~/tmp` (a subdirectory in your home directory)? In my .vimrc I have  `set backupdir=~/tmp/vim/` and `set directory=~/tmp/vim/` and this directory exists.

Comment: This did it. Thank you. It appears the issue was I didn't really understand what ~ means. I created a folder called 'tmp' in my home directory, and from there used:

    set backupdir=~/tmp/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [Security risk of vim swap files](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q4/145) on OS-Security mailing list. Putting your swap file in a world writable directory seems dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following line to my ~/.vimrc puts .swp files for currently open buffers under /tmp

`set directory=/tmp`

If you've tried this without issues are you able to verify that vim is reading your vimrc at all?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was I didn't really understand what ~ means. I created a folder called 'tmp' in my home directory, and from there used:

```
set backupdir=~/tmp//
```